# Cause: Cannot determine reply destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default reply destination set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

Using JMSConfig i am creating MQ Connection factory and i have InboundGatewayConfig and OutboundGatewayConfig , in Inbound Config i am reading the Message payload from one queue and in Outbound config sending the message to another queue and my goad is toset reply channel to acknowledge the sender queue once queue receive the message.

InboundGatewayConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class InboundGatewayConfig {

@Autowired
JmsConfig jmsConfig;

@Value("${fcb.inbound.receiver.queue.name}")
private String orderRequestDestination;

@Bean
public MessageChannel inboundOrderRequestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel inboundOrderResponseChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundOrderRequestChannel")
public OrderService orderService() {
    return new OrderService();
}

@Bean
public JmsInboundGateway jmsInboundGateway() {
    JmsInboundGateway gateway = new JmsInboundGateway(
            defaultMessageListenerContainer(),
            channelPublishingJmsMessageListener());
    gateway.setRequestChannel(inboundOrderRequestChannel());

    return gateway;
}


@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(jmsConfig.fcbCachingConnectionFactory());
    container.setDestinationName(orderRequestDestination);
    container.setRecoveryInterval(5000);
    container.setErrorHandler(t -> System.out.println("Error in JMS Configurations  \t" + t.getCause()));
    return container;
}

@Bean
public ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener channelPublishingJmsMessageListener() {
    ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener channelPublishingJmsMessageListener = new ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener();
    channelPublishingJmsMessageListener.setExpectReply(true);

    return channelPublishingJmsMessageListener;
}
}
```

OutboundGatewayConfig :

```
   @Configuration
    public class OutboundGatewayConfig {

 @Value("${fcb.inbound.receiver.queue.name}")
  private String orderRequestDestination;

   @Value("${fcb.inbound.response.queue.name}")
   private String orderResponseDestination;

   @Autowired
   JmsConfig jmsConfig;

   @Bean
   public MessageChannel outboundOrderRequestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel outboundOrderResponseChannel() {
  return new QueueChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundOrderRequestChannel")
  public JmsOutboundGateway jmsOutboundGateway() {
  JmsOutboundGateway gateway = new JmsOutboundGateway();
   gateway.setConnectionFactory(jmsConfig.fcbCachingConnectionFactory());
   gateway.setRequestDestinationName(orderRequestDestination);
   gateway.setReplyDestinationName(orderResponseDestination);
   gateway.setReplyChannel(outboundOrderResponseChannel());

   return gateway;
   }
  }
```

and this my service class

```
    public class OrderService {

     private static final Logger LOGGER =
          LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderService.class);

         public Message<?> order(Message<?> order) {
         LOGGER.info("received order='{}'", order);

         Message<?> status = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Accepted")
         .setHeader("jms_correlationId",
          order.getHeaders().get("jms_messageId"))
         .setReplyChannelName("inboundOrderResponseChannel").build();
          LOGGER.info("sending status='{}'", status);

          return status;
        }
       }
```

While running the application InboundGateway able to receive the message payload from request queue but while reply , giving bellow warning message.

2022-04-07 16:06:24.303  WARN 19408 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx.yyy.queue' - trying to recover. Cause: Cannot determine reply destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default reply destination set.

Comment: You send the message from your service to the `inboundOrderResponseChannel`, but I don't see who is subscribed to this channel. Perhaps you mean an `outboundOrderRequestChannel`. This way you would send a message to the `jmsOutboundGateway` which does populate a `jmsRequest.setJMSReplyTo(theReplyTo);` according your `gateway.setReplyDestinationName(orderResponseDestination);` and then the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` does `Destination replyTo = request.getJMSReplyTo();` to be sure where to send a reply.

Comment: Thank you for your response , can you share any working sample code which fulfill this requirement

Comment: Here should be something: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/basic/jms

Comment: And there are configurations in this test: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-jms/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/jms/dsl/JmsTests.java